# Map screen sleep (ctrl+shift+eject) to F19

Tags: keyboard, shortcut

How can I map screen sleep (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Eject</kbd>) to <kbd>F19</kbd>?

Other services I can find under keyboard shortcuts in settings but not this one.

Comment: Have You seen www.bettertouchtool.net ? Free tool for keyboard/mouse/trackpad shortcuts.

Comment: No I have not but I it seems to solve what I trying to do. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested out by Mateusz Szlosek, BetterTouchTool solves this for me where I very simply could set F19 to execute the Sleep Display action.